# This is a macron or a kana?

Tags: kana

"来てXまった" What is the X in following image?
Whole context :https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=manga&illust_id=69471473

[image: 来てXまった]

Comment: 「なんだか身体がムズムズ**し**てきて～」の「し」は読めたんですね。。。

Comment: Just for reference, this could not be a [macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron_(diacritic)) (nor a [Macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmanuel_Macron)).

Comment: @Earthliŋ Waht is correct English word to say the "[ー](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Donpu)"sign?Is the word "chouonpu" exact meaning a "ー" sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the hiragana character し

> 来て**し**まった